# Check if the value is inserted in form with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am developing a form with add more button. When I click the button, a set of field will be generated.
I have done the javascript validation for this, if all the added field is empty alert the message.
The code for that is:

```js
var n = document.getElementById('cnnumrows').value, i;

if ( frm_add_announcement.sublink[1].checked == true ) {
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        if ( (document.getElementById('url'+i).value.trim()=="") && ( document.getElementById("document"+i).files.length == 0 ) ) {   
            alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
            document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
            return false;   
        }
    }
}
```

I have to change this to if any of the fields is inserted value no need to alert and if all is empty alert.
Any suggestion

Comment: you have tagged it with jquery, why do you use plain js? perhaps we need some more information about your html structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var n = document.getElementById('cnnumrows').value;

if ((frm_add_announcement.sublink[1].checked)) {
  // will be set to true if some value is inserted 
  var someValue = false;
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById('url' + i).value || document.getElementById("document" + i).files.length) {   
      someValue = true;
    }
  }

  // if at this point someValue is still falsy - no values inserted, fire your alert
  if (!someValue) {
    alert("Enter a url/upload a file");
    document.getElementById('captionurl').focus();
    return false;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.form1.studentName.focus();
  function validateform(){
  var sname=document.form1.studentName.value;  
  var sclass=document.form1.studentClass.value;  
  var semail=document.form1.studentemail.value;  
  var sphone=document.form1.studentphone.value;
  var flag=false;
  var phoneno = /^\d{7}$/;
  if(sname==null || sname==""){
    alert("student name is empty\nFormate: XXXXXXXXX");
    flag=false;
    return false;
 }else {
   flag=true;
 }
 if(sclass==null || sclass==""){
   alert("student class is empty\nFormate: XXXxx");
   flag=false;
   return false;
 }else {
   flag=true;
 }
 if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(semail)) {  
    flag=true;
 }else{
    alert("student e-mail formate error \nFormate: example@example.xxx\n               example@example.xx");
    flag=false;
    return false;
 }
 if(sphone.match(phoneno)){  
   flag=true;
 }else{
    alert("student phone must contain atleast 7 digits\nFormate: XXXXXXX");
    flag=false;
    return false;
 }
   return flag;
 };
</script>
```